# Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class

Tags: android, layout

My layout XML file code is:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2.DefaultMessagesActivity">

<com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessagesList
    android:id="@+id/messagesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/input"/>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/input"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@color/gray_light"/>

<com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:attachmentButtonDefaultIconColor="@color/green"
    app:attachmentButtonDefaultIconPressedColor="@color/green_dark"
    app:inputButtonHeight="30dp"
    app:inputButtonIcon="@drawable/ic_send_selector"
    app:inputButtonMargin="16dp"
    app:inputButtonWidth="30dp"
    app:inputMaxLines="3"
    app:inputTextColor="@color/black"
    app:inputTextSize="18sp"
    app:showAttachmentButton="true"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

My XML file line #25 is:

```
 <com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput
```

I imported compile 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.2.0' to use source code.

My Manifest file looks like:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<permission
    android:name="com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="493026774418993" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".PermissionActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Register" />
    <activity android:name=".Profile" />
    <activity android:name=".InfoWindow" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BottomNavigation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bottom_navigation" />
    <activity android:name=".ChatMain" />
    <activity android:name=".ChatMessage" />

    <activity
        android:name=".DefaultDialogsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/BlueTheme"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".DefaultMessagesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/BlueTheme"/>


</application>
```

The error indicates   at com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2.DefaultMessagesActivity.onCreate(DefaultMessagesActivity.java:89) is

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_default_messages);
```

which has the xml layout file.

The error message is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2/com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2.DefaultMessagesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2.DefaultMessagesActivity.onCreate(DefaultMessagesActivity.java:89)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2.DefaultMessagesActivity.onCreate(DefaultMessagesActivity.java:89) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput.init(MessageInput.java:201)
    at com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput.init(MessageInput.java:151)
    at com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput.<init>(MessageInput.java:58)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.myhouse.woohyun.tripal2.DefaultMessagesActivity.onCreate(DefaultMessagesActivity.java:89) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried to import almost all files from source code but, it keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the layout file that is causing the error, plus the full Java stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: I edited layout file and error messages

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessageInput.init(MessageInput.java:201)` -- you will need to look at the source code to `MessageInput` and figure out what might trigger a `NullPointerException` here. If [this is the actual line](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/v.0.2.0/chatkit/src/main/java/com/stfalcon/chatkit/messages/MessageInput.java#L201), this looks like a possible bug in the library.

Comment: Could you try reverting to an older version of Chatkit e.g. `com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.1.2`? If it's a bug with this specific version of the library it's probably worth raising a bug report with the developers.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: using older version of Chatkit gives lots of errors....